# What URL encoding irregularities do browsers generally tolerate?

Tags: url, browser

Web browsers tend to do their best to recover malformed URLs.

Let's start with a baseline google query.

*http://www.google.com/search?q=myquery*

Which results in my browser (recent-ish build of Chrome) requesting.

> GET http://www.google.com/search?q=myquery HTTP/1.1

Fully expected behavior obviously.

Let's try putting an unescaped space into the mix.

*http://www.google.com/search?q=my query*

> GET http://www.google.com/search?q=my%20query HTTP/1.1

What if we use the % character? Because it's not followed by a valid character code the browser should escape it to %25

*http://www.google.com/search?q=i always give 100%*

> GET http://www.google.com/search?q=i%20always%20give%20100% HTTP/1.1

Chrome didn't escape the %!

Is space substitution the only URL transformation an average browser will/is expected to perform? Are there libraries for performing these kinds of URL "salvaging" transformations?

Comment: I hope you don't plan on relying any of this browser-specific and undefined behavior.

Comment: I am emulating browser behavior in an internal tool, with content that I have no control over. It's definitely more of a necessity than a desire.